# Count the number of records that match exploded column in pyspark.sql?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have an assignment that uses Spark 2.4 and part of the Yelp dataset. The part of the schema which we are to use from the business data is below and used in the same DataFrame:

```
"business_id": string
"categories": comma delimited list of strings
"stars": double
```

We are supposed to create a new DataFrame which groups the businesses by category, with the following columns:

```
"category": string exploded from "categories"
"businessCount": integer; number of businesses in that category
"averageStarRating": double; average rating of businesses in the category
"minStarRating": double; lowest rating of any restaurant in that category
"maxStarRating": double; highest rating of any restaurant in that category
```

So far I have been able to figure out how to use the explode command to break up the "categories" column into individual records and show the "business_id", "category", and "stars":

```
import from pyspark.sql functions as F
businessdf.select("business_id", F.explode(F.split("categories", ",")).alias("category"), "stars").show(5)
```

The above command gives me this as a result:

```
+--------------------+--------------+-----+
|         business_id|      category|stars|
+--------------------+--------------+-----+
|1SWheh84yJXfytovI...|          Golf|  3.0|
|1SWheh84yJXfytovI...|   Active Life|  3.0|
|QXAEGFB4oINsVuTFx...|Specialty Food|  2.5|
|QXAEGFB4oINsVuTFx...|   Restaurants|  2.5|
|QXAEGFB4oINsVuTFx...|       Dim Sum|  2.5|
+--------------------+--------------+-----+
only showing top 5 rows
```

What I can't figure out how to do is use aggregate functions to create the other columns. My professor says it all must be done in one statement. All of my attempts so far have led to errors.

My assignment says I will also need to remove any leading/trailing spaces on the newly created "category" column before doing any aggregations, but my attempts have all led to errors.

I feel this is the closest I've come but don't have any idea what to try next:

```
businessdf.select(F.explode(F.split("categories", ",")).alias("category")).groupBy("category").agg(F.count("category").alias("businessCount"), F.avg("stars").alias("averageStarRating"), F.min("stars").alias("minStarRating"), F.max("stars").alias("maxStarRating"))
```

Here is the error that comes along with that command:

```
`pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: "cannot resolve '`stars`' given input columns: [category];;\n'Aggregate [category#337], [category#337, count(category#337) AS businessCount#342L, avg('stars) AS averageStarRating#344, min('stars) AS minStarRating#346, max('stars) AS maxStarRating#348]\n+- Project [category#337]\n   +- Generate explode(split(categories#33, ,)), false, [category#337]\n      +- Relation[address#30,attributes#31,business_id#32,categories#33,city#34,hours#35,is_open#36L,latitude#37,lo`ngitude#38,name#39,postal_code#40,review_count#41L,stars#42,state#43] json\n"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, posting must have helped me work through it on my own. The command I posted above is very close, but I forgot to add the "stars" column to the select statment. The correct command is here:

```
businessdf.select(F.explode(F.split("categories", ",")).alias("category"), "stars").groupBy("category").agg(F.count("category").alias("businessCount"), F.avg("stars").alias("averageStarRating"), F.min("stars").alias("minStarRating"), F.max("stars").alias("maxStarRating")).show()
```